# How to send email images to node js server with Axios without a form?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

How do I send an image to my node js server with axios in react without a form?
I'm using nodemailer on server side to send an email with text and an image attachment.
The code below is what I have and it does not work as I'm not actually sending the file itself.
The code works fine for sending text.

```
import img from "./image.jpg";

const handleRequest = async () => {
  const body = {
    img,
  };
  await axios
    .post("http://localhost:3030/mail", body)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log("Email Sent Successfully");
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
};
```

Comment: Depends what Content-Type your API is designed to accept. But you could use a Blob and encode it in JSON data. Or you can create programatically a FormData and innsert your Blob in it. In any I think case you'lll have to encapsulate your image in a blob.

Comment: Okay but how do encapsulate my image in a blob?

Comment: You can have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471755/convert-image-into-blob-using-javascript this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob and this sould help too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects